# Unrecognized Attribute Name in User-Defined WCF Binding Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm writing a custom WCF binding that would like to control using configuration.  To be clear, I'm not talking about using the standard `<customBinding>` element, but rather inheriting from `Binding` and writing a full class.

My binding isn't very complicated, and I really only have one property that I would like to set through config, `useSsl`.  However, I am having difficulty getting .NET to recognize my configuration attribute even though I believe I have everything in order.

**Binding**

```
public class MyCustomBinding : Binding {

    public MyCustomBinding() {
        // Initialization
    }

    private bool _useSsl;

    public bool UseSsl {
        get { return _useSsl; }
        set { _useSsl = value; }
    }

    // Remaining implementation omitted

}
```

**Binding Configuration Element**

```
public class MyCustomBindingElement : StandardBindingElement {

      protected override Type BindingElementType {
          return typeof(MyCustomBinding);
      }

      // public const string UseSsl = "useSsl"
      [ConfigurationProperty(ConfigurationStrings.UseSsl, DefaultValue: true)]
      public bool UseSsl {
          get { return (bool)this[ConfigurationStrings.UseSsl]; }
          set { this[ConfigurationStrings.UseSsl] = value; }
      }


      // Remaining implementation omitted

}
```

**Binding Configuration Collection Element**

```
public class MyCustomBindingCollectionElement
    : StandardBindingCollectionElement<MyCustomBinding, MyCustomBindingElement> {}
```

I've registered the collection element in my **web.config** file:

```
  <extensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
          <add name="myCustomBinding" type="MyCustomWcf.MyCustomBindingCollectionElement, MyCustomWcf"/>
      </bindingExtensions>
  </extensions>
```

Then in my `<bindings>` section I add an instance of my custom binding.

```
<myCustomBinding>
    <binding useSsl="false" />
</myCustomBinding>
```

However, I receive the following configuration exception at runtime:

> Unrecognized attribute 'useSsl'. Note that attribute
>   names are case-sensitive

If I do not specify any properties on my binding, then it works.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does it compile although you receive this error?

Comment: Yes, syntactically everything is correct

Comment: Sorry, the error is not at compile time, I see it when I try to view the endpoint in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance. You specify ConfigurationStrings.UseSsl, but in the config you put useSsl.  Can you correct this and try again?

Comment: UseSsl is a constant for "useSsl".

Answer (score 0):

The "Properties" property of MyCustomBindingElement also need to be updated as below. Hope helpful ...

```
    protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties
    {
        get
        {
            var result = base.Properties;
            result.Add(new ConfigurationProperty("useSsl", typeof(bool)));

            return base.Properties;
        }
    }
```